# React-pdf-viewer warnings

Tags: reactjs, console.log, react-pdf-viewer

When the application is started these console messages appear.

```
Warning: getHexString - ignoring invalid character: 33.
Warning: getHexString - ignoring additional invalid characters.
Warning: Indexing all PDF objects.
```

Is there any way to remove these messages or possible solutions?

I put in context the code I am using:

```
import { Worker } from '@react-pdf-viewer/core';

root.render(
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Worker workerUrl="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/3.4.120/pdf.worker.min.js">
        <App />
      </Worker>
      <Modal />
      <FileModal />
    </Provider>
  </ThemeProvider>,
);
```

```
import '@react-pdf-viewer/core/lib/styles/index.css';
import '@react-pdf-viewer/default-layout/lib/styles/index.css';
import React from 'react';
import { Viewer } from '@react-pdf-viewer/core';
import { defaultLayoutPlugin } from '@react-pdf-viewer/default-layout';

import renderToolbar from './Toolbar';

const PDFViewer = ({ url }: PDFViewerProps) => {
  const defaultLayoutPluginInstance = defaultLayoutPlugin({
    sidebarTabs: (defaultTabs) => [defaultTabs[0]],
    renderToolbar,
  });
  return <Viewer plugins={[defaultLayoutPluginInstance]} fileUrl={`${url}#view=FitH`} />;
};

export default PDFViewer;
```

Versions in the :

```
    "@react-pdf-viewer/core": "3.12.0",
    "@react-pdf-viewer/default-layout": "^3.12.0",
    "pdfjs-dist": "3.4.120",
```

I hope to be able to remove or disable the console.logs